# What does Airspace 24 mean in this chart supplement?

Tags: airspace, chart-supplement

I found this line in Leesburg Executive Airport (KJYO)'s chart supplement:

[image: Airspace 24?]

I have looked in the Chart Supplement Legend under section 29 and there is no information about such an airspace. At the bottom of the legend it says to look at AIM's Chapter 3 for more details, but none can be found there. I googled this to no avail.

I am guessing that whatever it is might have something to do with KJYO's situation. It is located in the DC SFRA and has an FDC NOTAM "Leesburg Maneuvering Area" which lists required procedures when operating in and out of the airport. Don't know how "24" comes from all that, though.

Comment: Looks to me like something that should be submitted through the established channels as a mistake or in need of clarification--

Comment: It’s a special case related to the DC SFRA. NOTAM for this airport !JYO 01/008 JYO AIRSPACE SEE FDC 1/1155, 9/1811, 0/0053, 9/1812, 0/3929 ZDC SPECIAL SECURITY INSTRUCTIONS 2001150003-PERM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a mistake of some kind. The [next release of the Chart Supplement](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/) is valid from 2021-04-22 and the airspace line has been removed completely from the KJYO entry.